# How to satisfy to satisfy $(\int_0^1 [f(x)]^k \,\,dx)^{1/k} = \int_0^1 f(x)\,\, dx$ when $0<k<1$, $f(x) \neq 0,1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In order to satisfy $(\int_0^1 [f(x)]^k \,\,dx)^{1/k} = \int_0^1 f(x)\,\, dx$ where $0<k<1$ (strict inequality) and $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is assumed to be nontrivial from $0$ to $1$ - that is, there exists $0<c<1$ such that $f(c) \neq 0,1$,

what condition to $f(x)$ and/or $k$ need to be imposed? That is, is there some $0<k<1$ (not all) that satisfies the above, or is there some real function $f(x)$ that satisfies the above, or is there some $f(x)$ and $k$ that satisfies the above?

Or is this impossible?

Comment: For some $k$ or for all $0<k<1$? One possibility would be $f\equiv 1$

Comment: Edited my question. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $f(x)\geq 0$, and that $f(x)^{k}$ is in $L^1$.

For adequate positive functions $g$ and $h$, the Holder inequality  ($p>1, q>1, 1/p+1/q=1)$ say:

$$\int_0^1g(x)h(x)dx\leq (\int_0^1g(x)^pdx)^{1/p}(\int_0^1h(x)^qdx)^{1/q}$$

Take $k=1/p$ and $g(x)=f(x)^{k}$, $h(x)=1$, you get
$$\int_0^ 1 f(x)^{k}dx\leq (\int_0^1f(x)dx)^k$$

So you are in the case of equality; hence there exists a constant $a$ such that $g(x)=ah(x)$, and this imply that your function is constant.